# Valid email with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have problems to validate an email adress using preg_match().

This is the block of code i have.

```
if (VerifierAdresseMail($email))
  echo '<p>valide.</p>';
else
  echo '<p>not valid</p>';


  function VerifierAdresseMail($adresse) {
    $Syntaxe = '#^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$#';
    if (preg_match($Syntaxe, $adresse))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
```

this does not seem to work. it's just returning a white page. I can't see the error althought i have this in my application.ini

```
[developpement : production]


phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
phpSettings.track_errors = 1
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/Paris"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: it does work on ideone http://ideone.com/Jq7FL ; your regex needs improvement though

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do not use `preg_match()` to validate an email address. Use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter-var) instead:

```
if (filter_var($adresse, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     // valid
} else {
     // not valid
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should rather use this :

```
filter_var('e-mail@provider.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.

doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php